# Is there a formal (ideally BNF) typescript js language grammar (or only typescript subset)?

Tags: bnf, typescript

I'm looking for the Typescript grammar.
Not the parser-lexer, but only the formal grammar description.
I want to implement ts it's code folding and basic static code analyzing as plugin to one simple linux IDE for GNOME.

Comment: Why can't you just use the compiler itself to build the AST? It's open source after all...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The formal grammar is in Appendix A of the TypeScript Language Reference, version 1.8 if which is found [here](https://github.com/frenchy64/typescript-parser/blob/master/typescript.ebnf) (for current version)

Comment: There was actually a fun to read holiwar with devs on that matter in [a ticket](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15711) of typescript repo. The conclusion was to drop the specification because they have no resources to keep it up to date I take it.

Answer (score 3):

Since typescript is a strict superset of Ecmascript 5 (http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf/), you could exend any ecmascript bnf with syntax definitions from the Typescript spec.

A starting point could be: http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/1153976512034/ecmascriptA3.g

Answer (score 2):

An ANTLR4 grammar, but admittedly "not exactly ... to TypeScript standard" (it's a pain  there are so few official grammars for existing programming languages):

https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/typescript

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can find references in the source code, e.g. [compiler/tokens.js](http://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/fe3bc0bfce1f#src/compiler/tokens.ts)

Comment: He is asking for a grammar definition like http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/grammar.html .

Comment: It helps to find out which tokens are used and how tey are defined, but it is only lexer part.I need a set of rules in some formal notation to create parser and to be able to build AST from the given typescript text.

Comment: Chrome warns about that link: "The site ahead contains harmful programs"