# How can we get the Syntax Tree of TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, lexer, abstract-syntax-tree, parser-generator

Is there a process on getting a syntax tree of a compiler. We had been assigned on a project that needs to access typescript's syntax tree (which is opensource so we could see the whole compiler's code). But we don't know how to get it. I've been reading some articles in the Internet but I can't really find a user-friendly article or which is written in lehman's term. I believe some mentioned that the first step we need to do is to find the parsing step. But after that we had no idea what to do next.

Sorry for the noob question. :)

Comment: There's not much help for you, except perhaps from someone that has already dug through this code.  What you are learning is that in a big piece of software, it is hard to find your way around.  You need to spend time digging throught the source.  An obvious trick is to search the source code for the words "parse", "tree" and "node"; code for defining/building the AST is surely near where one of those is found unless the codebase is truly awful.  A standard tools loved by many programmers for this purpose is "grep".  If you don't know what that is, find out at wikipedia.

Comment: The answers on this later question may be of use... [TypeScript: get syntax tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20187928/typescript-get-syntax-tree)

Comment: The problem with getting ASTs from most compilers is hard; worse, the ASTs they have tends to be idiosyncratic.    Another alternative you might consider is finding a parser generator or even better a program transformation, and use (develop) a grammar for TypeScript; such tools often make it relatively to build an AST that is usuable for other-than-compiling purposes.

Answer (score 17):

The TypeScript compiler API is really quite easy to use. To parse a typescript file and obtain the AST, try the following:

```
const ts = require('typescript');
const sourceFile = ts.createSourceFile(filename,
    fs.readFileSync(filename).toString(), ts.ScriptTarget.ES6, false);
console.log(sourceFile.ast);
```

This generates the AST, for example:

```
{
  "kind": 251,
  "pos": 0,
  "end": 1097,
  "flags": 0,
  "bindDiagnostics": [],
  "languageVersion": 2,
  "fileName": "slidingWindow.ts",
  "languageVariant": 0,
  "scriptKind": 3,
  "referencedFiles": [],
  "amdDependencies": [],
  "statements": [
    {
      "kind": 218,
      "pos": 0,
      "end": 69,
      "flags": 0,
      "name": {
        "kind": 69,
        "pos": 10,
        "end": 22,
        "flags": 0,
        "text": "Accumulator",
        "kindDecoded": "Identifier"
      },
      "members": [
        {
          "kind": 148,
          "pos": 24,
          "end": 67,
          "flags": 0,
          "parameters": [
            {
              "kind": 139,
              "pos": 28,
              "end": 42,
              "flags": 0,
              "name": {
                "kind": 69,
                "pos": 28,
                "end": 32,
                "flags": 0,
                "text": "data",
                "kindDecoded": "Identifier"
              },
              "type": {
                "kind": 157,
                "pos": 33,
                "end": 42,
                "flags": 0,
                "elementType": {
                  "kind": 128,
                  "pos": 33,
                  "end": 40,
                  "flags": 0,
                  "kindDecoded": "NumberKeyword"
                },
                "kindDecoded": "ArrayType"
              },
              "kindDecoded": "Parameter"
            },
            {
              "kind": 139,
              "pos": 43,
              "end": 57,
              "flags": 0,
              "name": {
                "kind": 69,
                "pos": 43,
                "end": 49,
                "flags": 0,
                "text": "index",
                "kindDecoded": "Identifier"
              },
              "type": {
                "kind": 128,
                "pos": 50,
                "end": 57,
                "flags": 0,
                "kindDecoded": "NumberKeyword"
              },
              "kindDecoded": "Parameter"
            }
          ],
          "type": {
            "kind": 128,
            "pos": 59,
            "end": 66,
            "flags": 0,
            "kindDecoded": "NumberKeyword"
          },
          "kindDecoded": "CallSignature"
        }
      ],
      "kindDecoded": "InterfaceDeclaration"
    },
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to get the AST from a specific compiler or just get the syntax tree from a program in TypeScript? If you are interested in the later, then what you may need to do is grab a BNF grammar for TypeScript (starting point [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720955/is-there-a-formal-ideally-bnf-typescript-js-language-grammar-or-only-typescri)) and then use ANTLR for example. It has a tool named ANTLRWorks that allows you to visualise the syntax tree of a program.